# How to get all childNodes in JS including all the 'grandchildren'?

Tags: javascript

I want to scan a div for all childNodes including the ones that are nestled within other elements. Right now I have this:

```
var t = document.getElementById('DivId').childNodes;
for(i=0; i<t.length; i++) alert(t[i].id);
```

But it only gets the children of the Div and not the grandchildren. Thanks!

Edit: This question was too vague. Sorry about that. Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/F6L2B/

The body.onload script doesn't run at JSFiddle, but it works, except that the 'Me Second' and 'Me Third' input fields are not being assigned a tabIndex and are therefore being skipped over.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

This is the fastest and simplest way, and it works on all browsers:

```
myDiv.getElementsByTagName("*")
```

Comment: Note that unlike `childNodes` this does not get the "comment" or "text" descendant nodes (though that may very well be what you're after).

Comment: surprise that it is supported by IE6+

Comment: It get `Element`s, not `Node`s.

Comment: to get all child text (or comment) nodes, it is quite efficient to use `document.evaluate` with the parent as context node, and expression ".//text()"

Answer (score 35):

If you're looking for all `HTMLElement` on modern browsers you can use:

```
myDiv.querySelectorAll("*")
```

Comment: Using `myDiv.getElementsByTagName("*")` would almost certainly be faster, and would also work on much older browsers.

Comment: @rvighne your comment should have been the MARKED answer for this question.

Comment: This is actually ingenious. Kudos for the answer!

Comment: what id `myDiv` here?

Comment: Or directly: `document.querySelectorAll('#DivId *')` if one don't want/need to store `myDiv` separately.

Answer (score 16):

What about great-grandchildren?

To go arbitrarily deep, you could use a recursive function.

```
var alldescendants = [];

var t = document.getElementById('DivId').childNodes;
    for(let i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
        if (t[i].nodeType == 1)
            recurseAndAdd(t[i], alldescendants);

function recurseAndAdd(el, descendants) {
  descendants.push(el.id);
  var children = el.childNodes;
  for(let i=0; i < children.length; i++) {
     if (children[i].nodeType == 1) {
         recurseAndAdd(children[i]);
     }
  }
}
```

If you really only want grandchildren, then you could take out the recursion (and probably rename the function)

```
function recurseAndAdd(el, descendants) {
  descendants.push(el.id);
  var children = el.childNodes;
  for(i=0; i < children.length; i++) {
     if (children[i].nodeType == 1) {
         descendants.push(children[i].id);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a small change is required to your function to ensure that only element nodes (tags) are added to the results. You need to check that `if (el.nodeType == 1) { ... }` before adding it to the collection.

Comment: @Strelok - how does it look now - I may have fixed it a different way while you were writing that comment

Comment: No, it's still the same. `childNodes` returns *everything* including text inside nodes, such as `span`, attributes, comments, etc. If you need child nodes that are elements (span,div,label,input etc) you need to put the check for `if (el.nodeType == 1) { ... }`, where 1 indicates an ELEMENT node type.

Comment: 1. I think you've got an extra closing parenthesis at: descendants.push(el.id));
2. When I tried using copying your first example into the script section, I got a null for document.getElementById('DivId').childNodes, so I wrapped the part above the recurseAndAdd function into another function.
3. When I called that function followed by the recurseAndAdd function at body.onload, I got a slow script warning. Can you help me get this working? I'm not familiar with recursive functions...

Comment: I tried to clear up the question above. Maybe you can better see what I'm trying to do. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I've fixed one.  I don't follow why 2 happened, or how wrapping it in an anonymous function helped, but I'm glad you fixed it.  As for three, does the script run and complete?  If you have a big page the script could potentially run slowly, which may be the source of the error

Comment: @Mike - I understand 2 now - you probably had your script in you head section, so when it executed, the dom wasn't ready, hence the null.  Yeah, wrap in a function and call from body onload to fix.

Comment: How about using querySelectorAll?

`var t = document.getElementById('DivId').querySelectorAll('*');`

Comment: There's also a big difference between `querySelectorAll` and `getElementsByTagName`: the former returns a static node collection (it is not updated automatically), while the latter returns a **live** node collection. If you define `var allAnchors = document.querySelectorAll('a')` outside of your function scope and dynamically add new `a`'s, the collection will not include the elements newly added to the DOM. Check it out here: http://jsbin.com/deqozizi/1/edit

Answer (score 4):

If anyone else wants all **nodes** within that tree, and not just the *elements*, here's a 2022-era JS snippet:

```js
function getDescendantNodes(node, all = []) {
  all.push(...node.childNodes);
  for (const child of node.childNodes) 
    getDescendantNodes(child, all);
  return all;
}
```

Protip: afterwards, you can filter to your preferred `nodeType` with the `Node` global:  `nodes = getDescendantNodes($0);  nodes.filter(n => n.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)`