# How to wrap all text in html with another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For instance:

FROM

```
<div>
   whats up!
   <div> whats up2! </div>
   thank you for your help
   <div></div>
</div>
```

TO

```
<div>
   <span>whats up!</span>
   <div><span> whats up2! </span></div>
   <span>thank you for your help</span>
   <div></div> <!---STAYS THE SAME -->
</div>
```

How would I make something like this in jQuery or pure JavaScript?

Comment: well the only way I can think of is adding another element such as <t> around all the text first and then go from there..honestly put I have no clue where to start this method. What I am trying to achieve can be done if I go to all the text and just add a set of <t> identifier but I am trying to avoid that and sense it at the beginning of the html rendering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having this HTML:

```
<div id="container" >
   whats up!
   <div> whats up2! </div>
   thank you for your help
</div>​​​
```

You could do something like this:

```
var nodes = document.getElementById('container').childNodes;

$(nodes).each(function(ind, el){
    if(el.nodeType == 3)
        $(el).wrap('<span>');
    else
        $(el).wrapInner('<span>');
});
```

​
As far as I know, you can't get text nodes with jQuery (correct me if I'm wrong please'), so you can get them with pure JavaScript and use jQuery's method [wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

http://jsfiddle.net/hyJA6/2/

Comment: what if you want to apply this to every element in a body? I am having challenges getting the childNodes for body: is it `document.getElementsByTagName('body').childNodes;` ? EDIT: ACTUALLY i will figure that one out :D but thanks

Comment: Nope, with that you would get all the children of the first level. You should use some recursive function, this is a good start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321874/how-to-get-all-childnodes-in-js-including-all-the-grandchildren

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, the solution @davids provided, extended to work with deeper hierarchies, can be written as follows in "pure" jquery

```
$('#container')
.find('*')
.andSelf()
.contents()
.filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
})
.wrap('<span>')
```

This reads as follows: get the full contents for #container and all it's proper DOM children, keep only the text nodes (`nodeType == 3`) and wrap them in `<span>`.

Note this will get pretty slow if applied to large DOM trees.